# How to pass a json object as a parameter to a python function?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I would like to know if it is possible to call a function based on a json file as a parameter.

I mean, this is my function:

```
  def get_restaurant_bussiness_match(params):
   response = requests.get(url_bussiness_match, headers = headers, params=parameters)
    data = response.json()['businesses']
  
   name = parameters.get('name')
   addres1 = parameters.get('address1')
   mydata = {'name': name, 'addres1': address1}

   return pd.DataFrame(mydata,  index=[0])
```

**Input:**

```
parameters = {'name': 'Aperitivo',
             'address1': '5530 Spine Rd'}
```

Each time I call my function I execute this: get_restaurant_bussiness_match(parameters)

I would like to call my function but send as a parameter a json file with this format:

**myjson.json**

```
[{'name': 'Aperitivo',
 'address1': '5530 Spine Rd'},
 {'name': 'Tacos',
 'address1': '67 keneddy Rd}
  ]
```

Finally, be able to call my function and have as output a data frame like this:

**Output**

```
name       | address1
Aperitivo    5530 Spine Rd
Tacos        67 keneddy Rd
```

I would like to know the way that I should send my parameters to my function.

Comment: Please take at **kwargs, if it helps your scenario
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/

Comment: get_restaurant_bussiness_match() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given is not working

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what you’re stuck on here. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pd.json_normalize()`

```py
import json
import pandas as pd


with open('myjson.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

```
print(df)

        name       address1
0  Aperitivo  5530 Spine Rd
1      Tacos  67 keneddy Rd
```